# Is there a technique to remove an item of value 'this' from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a To-Do list with the ability to remove specific items from the list. I am currently trying to use 'localStorage' to essentially save the list on page refresh. However, when I delete an item from the list, the 'localStorage' does not work as intended and instead removes the first item in the array when you next load the page.

JS & jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-task', function () { // We use 'on' as the element is dynamically added
        console.log("'Delete' button pressed");

        var foo = $(this).closest('li');
        console.log(foo);


        $(this).closest('li').fadeOut(250, function() {

            arr.splice(foo, 1);

            $(this).remove(); // Dynamically remove the DOM element from the list
            localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(arr));

            console.log(arr);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('items'));

        });
    });
});
```

If interested, the HTML format of an item within the 'ul' list looks similar to this:

```html
<li><span class="text-task">5</span><span class="delete-task">x</span></li>
```

I am expecting the selected item from the list to be removed and store within the localStorage correctly when you next load the page.

**Update:**
As @Slim pointed out, 'foo' is a JS object and not an index.

My question is, how do I find the index of the specified item (the 'li') within the 'arr' array?

Comment: `arr.splice(foo, 1)` foo has to be an index but in your code it is a jQuery `li` object

Comment: What does `arr` look like?

Comment: I think this question mixes a lot of unrelated concepts. JQuery nor localStorage have nothing to do with how an array works. You need to find out your real issue here at first, and then try to explain it so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the parent of foo using `.parent()` ( https://api.jquery.com/parent/ ) and then find the index of given li by using `.index()` ( https://api.jquery.com/index/ )

```
...
var index = foo.parent().index( foo );
arr.splice(index, 1);
...
```

Also, you should try to cache jQuery object. Calling multiple times `$(this)` is calculating the same thing multiple times.
For example:

```
...
var $self = $(this)
var foo = $self.closest('li');
console.log(foo);
$self.closest('li').fadeOut(250, function() {
...
```

Also, good idea is to name variables containing jQuery objects starting with `$` - it's quite a common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**simulate this**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-id="1" >Coffee <span class="delete-task">x</span></li>
  <li data-id="2" >Tea    <span class="delete-task">x</span></li>
  <li data-id="3" >Milk   <span class="delete-task">x</span></li>
</ul>
```

use id value here

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-task', function () { 

     var id = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');

      for (var k in arr) {
        if (typeof arr[k] !== 'function') {
        if (arr[k].id == id) {
              //your codes
               break;
             }
           }
         }   

  });
```

I also recommend you use : https://github.com/localForage/localForage